# Information on IC with markings CT1668 HDB1144

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet

The IC looks similar to this; I found it on Google when searched for `CT1668 HDA1144`

[image: CT1668]

I don't even get the manufacturer name right; is it HEAD? Can anyone share its data sheet or at least some info on it? I couldn't find it on Google. Is `HDA1144` the next version of `HDA1134` shown in the image?

Comment: A simple google images search revealed this: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32460568373.html

Comment: is it same as `HDA1144`?

Comment: The part number looks like CT1668 which is the same. Where did you get it from? You can check the function is matching the one in the description.

Comment: then what is the other number? I found it on my spoiled induction stove control panel.

Comment: The first number listed is usually the part number. Other numbers are sometimes lot numbers or date codes. A common date code is YYWW, where YY is the last 2 digits of the year, and WW is the week of the year. So, 1134 could be 34th week of 2011.